# Мобильный интернет и сокеты

Tags: сокеты, android

C Wi-Fi телефон с ПК соединяется отлично через сокеты. Но вот с мобильного интернета -  ничего. Странно, но теперь заходит. Вроде сделал, не работало, повторил тоже самое, стало работать. Но вот теперь другая проблема. Допустим я хочу показать как работает приложение другому человеку. У него есть роутер. Если я имею доступ к настройке роутера, то все хорошо, а вот если нет? Что делать? как заставить роутер пропросить порты?

Comment: покажите, как соединяетесь с этим сокетом?

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что серверСокет открывается на телефоне, который работает через мобильный интернет? Тогда вполне возможно, что провайдер попросту не дает доступ к порту 8888. В общем, плохая идея - сервер через моб. интернет

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Сервер, естественно, на ПК, с проводного интернета.

Comment: а у "сервера-декстопа" IP, видимо, внутренний? А внешний статический на роутере (Вы же ещё по wifi подключались, значит, навернека есть роутер). В этом случае нужно просто пробросить нужный порт на роутере и в клиенте прописать правильный айпи.

Comment: ну да, а пробросить порт, это что именно?

Comment: гуглите, это сильно зависит от конкретного роутера. Вот, к примеру, как это делается на [dlink](http://dlink.ru/ru/faq/246/1156.html).

Comment: @перенаправление портов (Port Forwarding)

Comment: Перенаправление портов я сделал, на 5555 порт. Но все равно подключается только с фай фая. А вообще можно ли наладить связь на сокетах, с сетью где есть роутер, без настройки роутера? или это не возможно?

Comment: при подключении через "мобильную сеть" нужно подключаться не на внутренний айпишник, а на внешний. Зайдите на сайт вида [my ip](http://myip.ru/) и узнайте свой внешний айпи.

> А вообще можно ли наладить связь на сокетах, с сетью где есть роутер, без настройки роутера?

И да и нет. В некоторых случаях программа сама может попросить роутер пробросить ей порт (Так делает скайп, к примеру). А в некоторых случаях этого сделать нельзя - например, если у Вас нет внешнего правильного айпишника.

Comment: Обновил вопрос